# Tree modeling with hibernate xml config files

Tags: hibernate, tree

I've got a class called "Area". Each Area can have multiple sub-areas (of the same type).

I need to be able to determine sub-areas and root-areas. Sub-areas can have sub-areas themself.

This can be quite a few levels deep.

Example:

```
Rootarea  
|- Subarea 1  
|   |- Subarea 2  
|   |
|   |- Subarea 3
|
|- Subarea 4
|   |- Subarea 5

public class Area {

   private long id;

   private Area parent; 
   private List<Area> children;

   private String name;

   //getters and setters here ommitted
}
```

How do I model such a Java-class with Hibernate xml config files?

and ...

How do I load to memory the areas tree?

thanks

Comment: how are you planning store it in the database? All in same tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Area
{
    public Boolean isRootArea()
    {
        return getParent() == null;
    }
}


  <class name="Area" table="`AREA`">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="..." />
    </id>

    <bag name="children" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="parent_id" />
      <one-to-many class="Area" />
    </bag>
    <many-to-one class="Area" name="parent">
      <column name="parent_id" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>


var rootareas = session.createCriteria(Area.class).add(Restriction.IsNull("parent")).setFetchMode("children", FetchMode.eager).list();
```