# Map a one-to-zero association with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Could somebody explain me how to map a one-to-zero association with hibernate (using mapping xml files NOT annotations)?

These are the rules:

- A Menu can have 0 or 1 Area associated.
- An Area belongs to a Menu. (Or, if it is easier for you to modelize it: An Area can have 0 or 1 Menu associated).

Here are the desired TABLES (I want to use foreign keys):

```
TABLE MENU:
ID
NAME
FKID_AREA

TABLE AREA:
ID
NAME
FKID_MENU
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `FKID_AREA` from the `MENU` table, because it's not needed (and is even a problem, since it's redendant with `AREA.FKID_MENU`).

For the rest, this is described in the [Hibernate documentation on bidirectional one-to-one association mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-121):

```
<class name="Area">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="menu" 
        column="FKID_MENU" 
        unique="true"
        not-null="false"/>
</class>

<class name="Menu">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
   <one-to-one name="area" 
        property-ref="menu"/>
</class>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you!. (((Now, if you enjoy challenges, could you please try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702332/tree-modeling-with-hibernate-xml-config-files)))

Answer (score 0):

You should remove FKID_MENU from AREA table. As per your description, your hbm mapping would be below

```
<class name="Menu">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" cloumn="name"/>
    <many-to-one name="area" column="FKID_AREA" class="Area"/>
</class>

<class name="Area">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" cloumn="name"/>
</class>
```